# Datastore Preference progaurd return Error Message

Tags: android

I used datastore preference in a module with progaurd . I faced this error
**Didn't find class "androidx.datastore.preferences.PreferenceDataStoreDelegateKt"**

I added this rules but didn't work

```
# DataStore
-dontwarn androidx.datastore.core.DataStore.*
 -keep class androidx.datastore.preferences.core.* { *; }
 -keep class androidx.datastore.DataStoreDelegateKt { *; }
 -keep class androidx.datastore.preferences.core.PreferencesKeys { *; }
 -keep class androidx.datastore.*.** {*;}
 -keepclassmembers class * extends androidx.datastore.preferences.core.* {
     <fields>;
     <methods>;
     <init>();
 }
```

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd, I'd expect `-keep class androidx.datastore.*.** {*;}` to cover that. That said, it's odd that however you're minifying your code is failing to detect this...literally the only thing in that class is a single top-level function.  If you are calling it, then it shouldn't require a manual keep rule, and if you're not calling it, it shouldn't matter.  Could you add the crashing code?

Comment: Also, are you using R8 or ProGuard? (see https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code for which version of the Gradle plugin the switch was made at, as well as more info.)

Comment: @RyanM I used gradle plugin version 7.4.2

Comment: Again: Could you add the crashing code?  It's really quite strange that it would fail like this.